# Fancyhdr package and page numbering issues

Tags: page-breaking, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am using the `fancyhdr` package and I have got big issues with the page numbering. Indeed, the pages appear for each new title, but then I don't have anymore page numbers,
Here is the code furnish by the package, I hope that someone could explain me what is wrong:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
\chead{}
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\btypeout{\thechapter\space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}}  
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{} \renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{} \def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else \hbox{} \thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}
\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

This code, which is more efficient and maintainable than yours by using the "modern" syntax of `fancyhdr` works as intended (or as I interpret your code).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}  % avoids the need to redefine \cleardoublepage
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % to provide mock text for the example

%%% set up the headers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage} % the page number goes on the outer part
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape\leftmark} % the chapter title in the inner part

%% change how \chaptermark sets the marks
\makeatletter % we need to use \@chapapp
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \typeout{\thechapter\space #1}%
  \markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter\ #1}{}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
%\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{} % useless

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Xyz}
\kant[1-30]

\chapter{A new one}
\kant[31-60]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have checked, maybe I have made a mistake in my code... I am going to make tests...

Comment: This line was missing:\lhead{Chapter 3. \emph{Chapter\_title}} Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you issuing a `\lhead` command for every chapter? If so, you're misusing LaTeX and `fancyhdr`.